# Where does (will) Windows store the search index in its Anniversary Update?

Tags: windows-search, cortana, windows-10-v1607

On Tuesday, Microsoft is set to release the "Anniversary Update" of Windows 10.  If I am to understand this correctly, Cortana will replace the basic search functionality.  As someone trying to maintain some semblance of privacy in the digital age, I'm extremely concerned about this change.  The basic search allows the user to choose where the search index is stored.  From what I understand about Cortana, it is backed by Bing, meaning some information has to be communicated to Microsoft.  There are also unconfirmed reports that regardless of whether Cortana is connected to an account, Microsoft will still be collecting anonymous data about local searches.

I want to understand the extent of that data collection.  For example, if I'm searching business documents for, say, an account number, will Microsoft receive information about that search (even if "anonymized")?  Finally, will utilizing the search functionality in the Windows 10 Anniversary Update mean the contents of my drive will be indexed on their servers?